# Extract the error values of a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this hash

```
obj= {"User"=>["user_error", "Jack", "Jill1"], "Project"=>[ "project_error", "xxx"], "Task"=>[39], "Date"=>"date_error", "Time (Hours)"=>["time_error", "-2"], "Comment"=>"comment_error"}
```

I have to extract the error values of the keys and store them else where 
.The end result should be

```
error = ["user_error", "project_error","date_error","time_error","comment_error"]


obj = {"User"=>["Jack", "Jill1"], "Project"=>[ "xxx"], "Task"=>[39], "Date"=>nil, "Time (Hours)"=>["-2"], "Comment"=>nil}
```

could some one help how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too pretty, but you can do something like this:

```
errors = obj.each_with_object([]) do |(k, v), err|
  if v.is_a?(Array) && v.first =~ /_error$/
    err << v.shift
  elsif v =~ /_error$/
    err << v
    obj[k] = nil
  end
end
```

Results:

```
errors
#=> ["user_error", "project_error", "date_error", "time_error", "comment_error"]

obj
#=> {"User"=>["Jack", "Jill1"], "Project"=>["xxx"], "Task"=>[39], "Date"=>nil, "Time (Hours)"=>["-2"], "Comment"=>nil}
```

---

You could DRY the code a bit by transforming all values to arrays first, but you will get empty arrays instead of `nil` for `Date` and `Comment` keys:

```
errors = obj.each_with_object([]) do |(k, v), err|
  obj[k] = v = [v].flatten
  err << v.shift if v.first =~ /_error$/
end

errors
#=> ["user_error", "project_error", "date_error", "time_error", "comment_error"]

obj
#=> {"User"=>["Jack", "Jill1"], "Project"=>["xxx"], "Task"=>[39], "Date"=>[], "Time (Hours)"=>["-2"], "Comment"=>[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
errors = []
obj.map do |class_name, strings| 
  errors.push(strings.shift) # shift remove the first element of the array
  obj[class_name] = strings
end
```